# Does Idele group of norm 1 preserved by the norm?

Tags: number-theory, class-field-theory, adeles

I should explain my question in detail as of now I'm sure it makes no sense.

Let $K$ be a global field (in particular I care about the characteristic $p$ case.)

Then its Idele group $I_K$ has a homormorphism into $\mathbb{R}_+$ defined by the map $a \mapsto\prod_P q_P^{-v_P(a)}$ and this is called the idelic norm. This map has a kernel say $I_K^0$.

For $K\subset L$ there is a natural norm map $N_{L/K}:I_L\rightarrow I_K$.

I want to know whether $N_{L/K}I_L^0\subset I_K^0$. I tried to do some calculation using some facts I know and I have not been able to attain a conclusion yet.

Comment: The ("metric") norms on extensions of the "bottom" field's completions are obtained by composing the bottom field's (metric) norms with the local Galois norms.

Comment: By that do you mean $|a_\beta|_\beta=|N_{L_\beta/K_P}a_\beta|_P$ for $\beta|P$? I am not sure whether I understood your statement correctly.

Comment: @paulgarrett I forgot to tag you.

Comment: Yes, $|a|_w=|N_{L_w/K_v}(a)|_v$ for $a\in L_w$ and $w|v$. Thus, at the "bottom" (namely, $\mathbb Q$ for the number-field case, and a genus-zero field for the function-field case) the product rule holds by reducing to primes and using the fact that the "integers" are a principal ideal domain...